# Uninstall OS running in dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uninstall

Supposing I have two Linux distributions, in dual boot (the GRUB menu appears and ask me what to choose):

- Ubuntu 14.04
- elementary OS

Adding a new one is very simple: just insert the installation device and start installing.

What about uninstalling one? How can I uninstall *elementary OS*, for example?

Can I do that only by formatting/deleting that partition?

Comment: Take a look at [OS-Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller).

Comment: @Mitch I installed it. Seems to be a very simple application. Don't forget to post an answer. :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [OS-Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller)

> OS-Uninstaller is a small graphical tool to perform a clean and quick
>   uninstall of any operating system (Windows, MacOS, Ubuntu, other Linux
>   distribution..) of your computer.  OS-Uninstaller is a free software, licenced under GNU-GPL. <sup>[OS-Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller)</sup>